# Rewriting AppleScript to appscript-rb, setting variable in Keyboard Maestro

Tags: ruby, macos, applescript, keyboard-maestro, sourceforge-appscript

I need to set a variable in Keyboard Maestro, and the documentation states that this can be done with AppleScript:

```
tell application "Keyboard Maestro Engine"
  make variable with properties {name:"My Variable", value:"New Value"}
end tell
```

I'm trying to transform this to appscript-rb notation, so far I've got

```
Appscript.app('Keyboard Maestro Engine').
  make(:variable, properties={:name=>'var1', :value => 'val1'})
```

I've documented a lot of successful snippets here: http://reganmian.net/wiki/appscript, and many of them follow the pattern above, but this snippet does not work, it gives "unknown keyword parameter name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the syntax of your command wrong (hard to imagine with AppleScript's clear and well defined syntax, I know!).

The command should be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "rubygems";
require "appscript";

kme = Appscript.app('Keyboard Maestro Engine');
kme.make(:new => :variable, :with_properties => {:name => "My New Variable", :value => "New Value 2"});
```

I found [this draft book of Scripting Mac Applications With Ruby](http://www.apeth.com/rbappscript/00intro.html#XXXtoc) helpful in figuring out how to translate the AppleScript code to ruby.

BTW, if you know the variable already exists, it's easier to use just the simple reference get/set commands:

```
kme = Appscript.app('Keyboard Maestro Engine');
p kme.variables["My Variable"].value.get;
kme.variables["My Variable"].value.set("Next Value");
p kme.variables["My Variable"].value.get;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've got quite a bit of experience rewriting AppleScript to AppScript, but this one stumped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use defaults write and defaults read to store your variables in your own plist.

Answer (score 0):

So I would love a more elegant answer, but based on Phillipe Martin's comment, this is one way that works:

```
defaults write reganmian.net.researchr prelude "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;export LANG=en_US.UTF-8;declare -x LANG=en_CA.utf-8"
defaults write reganmian.net.researchr ruby "/usr/local/bin/ruby -KU"
defaults write reganmian.net.researchr path "/Users/Stian/src/folders2web"
```

and then

adding this to the Keyboard Maestro "execute shell command

```
`defaults read reganmian.net.researchr prelude`
`defaults read reganmian.net.researchr ruby` `defaults read reganmian.net.researchr path`/dokuwiki.rb image
```

It works, but it looks very unwieldy.

*(The two things that would make this easier, one is being able to configure the shell that Keyboard Maestro uses to execute shell commands - this is not your default shell, does not respect the ~/.profile, and does not have the right codepage, path, etc - and the other is allowing definition of arbitrary variables in the settings, which could be inserted with %variable%).*

Comment: You can specify the shell to execute the same way you always would, using a #! at the start of the script.  The shell is invoked as a non-interactive, non login shell, and so the shell does not execute the .profile or any other settings files.  See the INVOCATION section of "man sh".